# Reassigning a range from one sheet to another

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have this:

```
const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
const sh1 = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
const sh2 = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet2');
const range1 = sh.getRange('A1:C3');
```

I want to do something like this:

```
var range2 = sh2.range1();
```

Basically range2 is a copy of range1, but within sh2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [getA1Notation()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#geta1notation):

```
const range2 = sh2.getRange(range1.getA1Notation());
```

### Solution:

```
function myFunction() {

const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
const sh1 = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
const sh2 = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet2');
const range1 = sh1.getRange('A1:C3'); 
  
const range2 = sh2.getRange(range1.getA1Notation());
}
```